# secure use of authorization token in cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am developing single page application in PHP. I am fetching products data from external API using cURL. API is secured and I have to provide the token.

I want to know that is it secure way to add this token in my `index.php` page (like I did in the below example), I don't want that someone else misuse the token by inspecting or getting it from the server

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = "http://example.com/v1/products";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type:application/json',
      'Authorization: Bearer abcxyzabac*******'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    }
    else {
        $decoded = json_decode($response, true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    

</head>

<body>

  <?php
    foreach($decoded as $dec)
    {
       echo $dec->name;
    }
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why shouldn't that be secure? If anybody is able to read files from your server, the attacker could also read all other places where you could store such a token

Comment: Your PHP code isn't sent back to the client. PHP is a server side language, which means that it gets executed on the server and only return what you explicitly output (or that are outside of a PHP block)

Comment: Some projects store api key in .env files, I am thinking that because of security reason they are saving in another location. I have no idea but maybe they can get from inspect or something else

Comment: The reason for `.env` is mainly to be able to run the code in different environments that might need different credentials. It's a way to keep the application code the same and only needing to change one file containing the environment specific credentials. Another reason to keep it in a separate file is so you can ignore that file when you store the code in some version control system, like git (you don't want to store credentials in your repositories)

Comment: It means I am on the right path?

Comment: "on the right path" depends on so many things - seing the given code, I would highly recommend to use a templating engine (to seperate PHP and HTML), and a dedicated HTTP client (like Guzzle) such that you don't have to use raw cURL calls

Comment: The reason why I didn't use template that it is a single page only
I have used Guzzle in Laravel, but this application is just fetching 3 api's

Comment: And if I have to use template I have to create a separate file for the cURL part and include it in the index, This is right?